# How CSS Hover Effect?

Tags: html, css

hi friends I want to make that design follows the hover effect .

design

```
codepen.io/premiumcuyuz/pen/wwxgxz
```

I want to give effect

```
codepen.io/wojtek1150/pen/jkdrqo
```

Comment: your question is unclear...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean yet the hover effect is given in CSS using the :hover attribute

for example you have some button given the   `id='testme'`

```
#testme
{
 background-color: blue;
 font-size: 10px;
}

#testme:hover
{
 background-color : green;
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

this should enable the hover effect. and once hovering some element with your cursor it should change it's color from blue to green